# Does this cause a memory leak? Allocating new objects in function call

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

The following code is taken from a DirectX tutorial and slightly modified by me:

```
void Initialize()
{
    //  case 1
    m_camera.SetLookAt( new D3DXVECTOR3( x_component, y_component, z_component  ) );

    //  case 2
    m_camera.SetLookAt( &D3DXVECTOR3( x_component, y_component, z_component ) );

    //  case 3
    {
    m_camera.SetLookAt( &D3DXVECTOR3( x_component, y_component, z_component ) );
    }

    //more stuff to do here
 }

void CCamera::SetLookAt( D3DXVECTOR3* pLookAt )
{
    m_lookAt.x = pLookAt->x;
    m_lookAt.y = pLookAt->y;
    m_lookAt.z = pLookAt->z;

    //delete pLookAt;   // solution for case 1?
}
```

m_camera is instance of class CCamera, which has a private member D3DXVECTOR3 m_lookAt.
The SetLookAt() function takes a pointer to a D3DXVECTOR3.

My question is, what is the difference between the ways this pointer is provided (case 1 and 2) ?

As far as my understanding goes, in case 1, the D3DXVECTOR is allocated from heap. The created pointer is passed to SetLookAt(), which copies the data and quits. Then, Initialize() quits, without releasing the memory taken by the D3DXVECTOR, resulting in a memory leak. The possible solution would be to uncomment the last line in SetLookAt().

In case 2, D3DXVECTOR is allocated on stack and its adress is passed to SetLookAt. This time, the D3DXVECTOR is freed only when Initialize() is finished.

Is my understanding correct? And what if I (in case 2) want the memory the D3DXVECTOR3 occupies to be freed as soon as the SetLookAt() function ends? Will wrapping the SetLookAt() in curly brackets (case 3) suffice to force the created D3DXVECTOR3 to be freed once SetLookAt is done?

Also, would it make any difference if the call to SetLookAt() (in all 3 cases), the vector would be called using literal values,  e.g. D3DXVECTOR3( 8.0f, 0.0f, 5.0f  ) instead of D3DXVECTOR3( x_component, y_component, z_component ) ?

Comment: `solution for case 1?` Bad solution, the function should not know whether pointer passed to it must be deleted. Move this `delete` to the caller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in this case you should use const reference

```
void CCamera::SetLookAt( const D3DXVECTOR3& lookAt )
```

Case 2 and case 3 are the same
And there's no difference in how it works when you create the vector:
`D3DXVECTOR ( D3DXVECTOR3( 8.0f, 0.0f, 5.0f )` or `D3DXVECTOR3( x_component, y_component, z_component )`

Answer (score 0):

In cases 2 and 3 (which are the same) you are passing a pointer to an stack-allocated anonymous temporary. That's fine since the stack will not unwind until the function has 
returned so your pointer will remain valid.

The anonymous temporary is popped from the stack once .SetLookAt has completed, in both 2 and 3 which is why {} is redundant.

Case 1 will leak without the delete you currently have commented.

Comment: Actually cases 2 and 3 are illegal and should result in a compiler error.

Comment: but it seems to me that in msvc this does compile and issues a warning

Comment: Yes it does compile on msvc, although gcc will not allow you to pass a reference to an anonymous temporary. But all this is bad practice.

Comment: @Bathsheba for the record, older versions of GCC were accepting 2 and 3 (but this is not binding a reference to a temporary, it is taking the address of a temporary, which is subtly different).

Comment: @Bathsheba - "passing a reference to an anonymous temporary" is exactly what he *should* be doing. Instead, he's trying to get a pointer to an anonymous temporary, which *is* a bad idea.

Comment: I thought that passing a reference to an anonymous temporary was even worse!

Comment: It is OK if the reference is a `const` reference. It is illegal if it isn't (although, again, MSVC allows it).

Comment: @Bathsheba I omitted to say `const` reference, which is of course important.